# DataTables error with fixedColumns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables in my website, and I'm trying to do sticky columns, with "fixedColumns", but when I add it to my javascript, it turns up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLPCj.png

can someone help me??
thx.